PhD without any direction
I am a PhD student in a third world country in Mathematics in my fourth year. I have some serious concerns regarding my PhD. My advisor is very little involved in my things. I have some small results, but whatever I do he always says it's not good enough. As per his rules, one is not allowed to collaborate with any of his other students or students in related areas.
I now feel hopeless everyday. We meet once a month for max. half an hour. He doesn't respond to calls or messages and now I am in my 4th year without any clear direction or problem to solve from his side. Everyday I am going into deeper depression and turning anxious. I am starting to think about other career alternatives. But as I wasted 4 years, I want to get the degree but have no idea how to please him. Changing advisor is not an option here at my place.
What can I do?

Has this four years been mostly coursework or mostly research? Where do you get problems to work on?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/211135/what-should-i-do-if-my-advisor-is-incorrectly-advising-me Does this answer your question?

@Buffy I found out problems on my own basically something was done in one setting and I was trying to do in other setting that's all. First two years were coursework

Out of curiosity, in which ways do you believe ‘in some third world country’ informs this question?

"Once a month for half an hour" sounds seriously inadequate to me. I usually met with my Ph.D. students once a week for at least an hour, and I think most of my colleagues have similar schedules.

@AndreasBlass not even that. There were instances where we didn't meet even for anhour as he always says he is busy so mostly like half an hour. In half an hour it's difficult to even express my ideas . So basically nothing happens in that time also. I don't know at times I feel extremely frustrated and anxious.
